# JavaScript regular expression to parse Latex \frac

Tags: javascript, regex, latex

I am parsing Latex formula in one of my mathematical applications to convert to custom format. My requirement is when ever the Latex formula had a fraction i.e.  `\frac{a}{b}` it has to be converted into `{a}/{b}`

The below is regular expression I am using:

```
\\frac\{(((?![\{\}]).)*)\}\{(((?![\{\}]).)*)\}
```

This is parsing fine a simple case like `\frac{a}{b}`, but when my fraction had sub fractions or curly braces inside it's completely failing

For example to parse complex string like this: (the parser failing for this case)

```
\frac {(\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a})^{10^{15}_1}}{(\frac{a}{c})^{\frac{s}{d}}}\int_{a}^{b}
```

The below is the complete code I am using:

```js
function fraction(input) {
     while (input.search(/\\frac\{(((?![\{\}]).)*)\}\{(((?![\{\}]).)*)\}/) >= 0) {
      input = input.replace(/\\frac\{(((?![\{\}]).)*)\}\{(((?![\{\}]).)*)\}/g, "{$1}/{$3}");
     }
     if (input.search(/\\frac/) >= 0) {
      input = fraction(input);
     }
     return input;
    };
```

```html
Enter formula: <input id="formula" onblur="console.log(fraction(document.getElementById('formula').value));"/> <button>Go</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may do it for you:

```
/\\frac\s*{((?!\\frac{).*?)}{((?!\\frac{).*?)}/
```

It replaces from the inner "atomic" `frac` until all are replaced.

```js
function fraction(input) {
  var re = /\\frac\s*{((?!\\frac{).*?)}{((?!\\frac{).*?)}/,
      bMatch = true;
  
  while (bMatch) {
    bMatch = false;
    input = input.replace(re, function(tot, a, b) {
      bMatch = true;
  
      //console.log("[" + a + ", " + b + "]");
      return '{' + a + '}/{' + b + '}';
    });
  }
  return input;
}


function doAction() {
  console.log(fraction(document.getElementById('formula').value));
}
```

```html
Enter formula: <input id="formula" value="\frac {(\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a})^{10^{15}_1}}{(\frac{a}{c})^{\frac{s}{d}}}\int_{a}^{b} " onblur="doAction()"/> <button onClick="doAction()">Go</button>
```

Comment: I guess this code might have a slight problem. It will output ```'{8}{\\frac{8}/{2}}'``` if the input is ```fraction("\\frac{8}{\\frac{8}{2}}")```.